# InternetExplorer 11 custom unicode character won't display

Tags: css, unicode

This perfectly works on FF and Chrome. Some characters of custom font-face used as icons. The bulletproof font face definition is used but still won't work on IE11.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/tp/" class="facebook-link">
   <i class="icon t-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tp-icons';
  src:  url('fonts/tp-icons.eot?hwkxxh');
  src:  url('fonts/tp-icons.eot?hwkxxh#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/tp-icons.ttf?hwkxxh') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/tp-icons.woff?hwkxxh') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/tp-icons.svg?hwkxxh#tp-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icon {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'tp-icons' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Enable Ligatures ================ */
  letter-spacing: 0;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;
  font-variant-ligatures: discretionary-ligatures;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.t-facebook:before {
  content: "\e905";
}
```

Any ideas? If I change the content part of the `.t-facebook:before` from "\e905" to "X" or something, it works even in IE11.

EDIT: I figured out that if I comment out the

```
 -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
```

part, it works in IE11 as well. It is interesting because IE11 should be  compatible with these...

Comment: Stupid question of course, but why do you even need ligatures to be enabled for an icon containing one (1) glyph?

Comment: Why is it stupid? And I don't need nigatures. This is not my project, it was written by someone else I just need to fix it.

Comment: Well, if removing font-feature-settings fixes the issue, I wouldn't spend too much time on it.